# Unhandled exceptions filter in a windows service

Tags: .net, exception, windows-services

I am creating a windows service and want to know best practices for this. In all my windows Program I have a form that asks the user if he wants to report the error and if he answers yes I created a case in FogBugz. What should I do in a windows service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also have a system tray representation of the service which would show a small notification about any errors and ask the user whether they want it reported or not. I think that it is still better to be able to give the user the choice whenever you are sending 'out' data from their computer.

Comment: As a service you may not have a user logged in to the machine therefore no desktop.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're not going to have a user interacting with the program, I'd say make configuration variable (in an app.config file) responsible for sending/not sending the data.  That way users who don't want to report errors can just change a flag in a config file.  I'd personally have it turned on by default and then give them guidance on how to turn it off it they wanted to.